# How do I detect the next keypress after a hotkey in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey, keyboard-events

I want to make an AutoHotKey script where the following things happen, in order when <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed.

- The next keystroke after <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is recorded
- If it is <kbd>g</kbd> then Google is opened
- If it is <kbd>Esc</kbd> then the computer is locked
- (Many more conditons like the two above)

I know how to do all of these things except detect the next keystroke **after** <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in variables **A_PriorHotKey** and  **A_TimeSincePriorHotkey** to detect the next keystroke after Win+Space and to check whether the hotkey has been pressed recently (otherwise it could activate hours later):

```
#Space:: return

; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys:

#If (A_PriorHotKey = "#Space" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 2000)

    ; If the hotkey was pressed recently (2 seconds)
    ; and g is pressed, then open google:

    g:: Run https://www.google.com ; open google (duh)


#If ; turn of context sensitivity
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks!